# Defining a function that returns a slice of variable size in golang

Tags: arrays, function, go

I would like to build a function that returns a slice of any size.  I know I can do

```
func BuildSlice() [100]int { return [100]int{} }
```

but I would like to be able to return slices of different sizes from the same function.  Something like:

```
func BuildSlice(int size) [...]int { return [size]int{} }
```

I've tried the above as well as

```
func BuildSlice(size int) []int { return [size]int{} }
```

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: First of all, `[100]int` is not a slice, it's an array. `[]int` is a slice. Please consider reading http://blog.golang.org/slices and http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

Comment: You are profoundly mixing arrays and slices. Additional to the blog post mentioned by Kavu work your way through the tour of Go at http://tour.golang.org/#1 and effective Go http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html

Comment: To clarify in short what the other comments have referred to: A `slice` is a scoped view of an array. The array can either be explicit, as in: `var a [100]int` - **array** of int, len==100
, `s := a[25:50]` - **slice** of `a`, giving access to elements 25.. **49** of `a` , or implicit, as in: `s := make([]int, 10, 100)` - slice with access to 10 elements of the array implicitly allocated by the second parameter of `make()` - `capacity`.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

First of all, slices are already of "variable size": `[100]int` and `[...]int` are array type definitions.

`[]int` is the correct syntax for a slice, and you could implement the function as:

```
func BuildSlice(size int) []int {
    return make([]int, size)
}
```

This will return a slice of zero values with the desired size, similar to what your array version does.

Answer (score 5):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Making slices, maps and channels](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Making_slices_maps_and_channels)
>
> The built-in function make takes a type T, which must be a slice, map
>   or channel type, optionally followed by a type-specific list of
>   expressions. It returns a value of type T (not *T). The memory is
>   initialized as described in the section on initial values.
>
> `Call             Type T     Result`
>
> ```
> make(T, n)       slice      slice of type T with length n and capacity n
> make(T, n, m)    slice      slice of type T with length n and capacity m
> ```
>
> The size arguments n and m must be of integer type or untyped. A
>   constant size argument must be non-negative and representable by a
>   value of type int. If both n and m are provided and are constant, then
>   n must be no larger than m. If n is negative or larger than m at run
>   time, a run-time panic occurs.
>
> ```
> s := make([]int, 10, 100)       // slice with len(s) == 10, cap(s) == 100
> s := make([]int, 1e3)           // slice with len(s) == cap(s) == 1000
> s := make([]int, 1<<63)         // illegal: len(s) is not representable by a value of type int
> s := make([]int, 10, 0)         // illegal: len(s) > cap(s)
> ```

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := make([]int, 7, 42)
    fmt.Println(len(s), cap(s))
    t := make([]int, 100)
    fmt.Println(len(t), cap(t))
}
```

Output:

```
7 42
100 100
```